# c# export DataGridView content

Tags: c#, datagridview, export

I export some dummy data from a datagridview, ex. "1.000"

```
private void btnSaveCalibTable_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();
        sfd.Filter = "Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            System.IO.StreamWriter file = new 
System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\Desktop\\sample.txt");
            try
            {
                string sLine = "";
                for(int i=0; i<dgvSensorCalibTable.Rows.Count-1; i++)
                {
                    for(int j=0; j < dgvSensorCalibTable.Columns.Count; j++)
                    {
                        sLine += dgvSensorCalibTable.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value + ", ";
                    }
                    
                    sLine += "\n";
                }
                file.WriteLine(sLine);

                file.Close();
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Export Complete.", "Program Info", 
MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
            catch (System.Exception err)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(err.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                file.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

when I export it to a .txt file I get back :
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,

My question is how to export it as it is in the datatable 1.000 instead of 1?

Answer (score 1):

Getting the numbers to format properly will depend on the underlying cell data types.

To format numbers, the `String.Format(..)` method works well. However, if the cells data type is a `string` you may need to convert the string to a `decimal`.

Example, if the cells are of `decimal` type cells, then you could use…

```
sLine += String.Format("{0:0.000}", (decimal)dgvSensorCalibTable.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);
```

Again, this assumes the underlying data are `decimal` types.

In addition, to avoid getting the extra unwanted comma (,) at the end…

```
string formattedLine = String.Format("{0:0.000}", (decimal)dgvSensorCalibTable.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value);
sLine += formattedLine;
if (j < dgvSensorCalibTable.Columns.Count - 1) {
  sLine += ",";
}
```

[Standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) … is the MS documentation and has a lot of info and examples using the `String.Format` method.

Comment: "Specified cast is not valid", this is what I get

Comment: Well, as I stated in my answer, this will depend on what “type” the underlying data is in the grid. Your question does not specify what the cell “type” is. How is the data put into the grid and what “type” is it? I am aware that you stated this is “dummy data”, however, when using “non dummy data” what “type” is it? if the data is of “type” `string`, then, you may need to parse the string to some numeric value.

Comment: It is unclear what the “real” data may be. In addition, if the current code (using dummy data) is simply adding the text character “1” to the cells, then couldn’t you simply change the “1”s to “1.000”? I was  under the impression the data would be of a “numeric” type. This is unknown. It may help to describe how the non-dummy-data is input into the grid and specifically what “type” the cells are for cells you want to format.